# Is browser a dependency?

Tags: licensing, dependencies

An application has a few links, where it needs to open a browser window. Does this mean the browser is a dependency and a liscence for the browser is needed?

Comment: Are you distributing the browser with your application?

Comment: No.I am not distributing any browser.User can use any but I will recommend then chromium(not chrome) due to some reason.

Answer (score 4):

If you bundle a browser (or one of its components, such as the gecko engine) as part of your application or force the user to install it, it's a dependency like any other component your application might use.

Otherwise, it's not a dependency, at least not in the traditional sense - people who use the application can decide what browser to install, or, in theory, could even implement one on their own.

Comment: My app will require users to have a browser but it can be any browser.

Comment: It will basically have an option open in browser.

Comment: That sounds like a similar style of "dependency" as "runs on linux" or "runs on windows" - a prerequisite but not a dependency in a license sense. (yes, I know this statement of mine can be nit-picked due to licensing of foundation libraries of the OS etc)

Comment: If the software needs a browser to be present in order to function, then that is a dependency in the *traditional* sense. If that browser is not part of the installed package, but something the user needs to provide themselves, then it is not a dependency in the *licensing* sense.

Comment: Is it same with asking an user to install python or some other programming language.Just asking.